# Api 23 permission compile time checking

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

Hey I am updating to android api 23 but i having trouble making sure all the spots that require permissions from the user have been properly handled. Is there a way to find all the methods that require the user to grant permission other then manually walking through the app trying all branches?

Comment: if you remove the permission from the manifest does the latest Lint warn you about it? _just a thought_

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Plugin that do what you want:
[AndroidPermissionsUsage](https://github.com/RomainPiel/AndroidPermissionsUsage)

but, as he mentioned in readme file, this is an experiment and it doesn't do perfectly what it's supposed to do.
so,  i suggest you to upgrade your application with this easy to use library: [Let](https://github.com/canelmas/let)

just add:

```
@AskPermission({
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA
})
private void skipTutorial() {
// permissions needed for best experience are granted; let' go to the app's home screen
startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
}
```

or this library: [permiso](https://github.com/greysonp/permiso)

and use this code:

```
Permiso.getInstance().requestPermissions(new Permiso.IOnPermissionResult() {
@Override
public void onPermissionResult(Permiso.ResultSet resultSet) {
    if (resultSet.isPermissionGranted(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
        // Contact permission granted!
    }
    if (resultSet.isPermissionGranted(Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR)) {
        // Calendar permission granted!
    }
}

@Override
public void onRationaleRequested(Permiso.IOnRationaleProvided callback, String... permissions) {
    Permiso.getInstance().showRationaleInDialog("Title", "Message", null, callback);
}
}, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR);
```

Comment: He's not wanting a way to get permission, he's asking if there's a way to locate all places in his code base that would _require_ him to ask for permission.

Answer (score 0):

Grab all the permissions from the manifest that match from the list of [dangerous permissions.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous)

[image]

Then for each permission, go to edit -> find in path -> and the keyword for the permission group, in my example I'm using Location.

[image]

[image]

Then in your results panel find the first most likely occurence this permission is used, in this case MainActivity:

[image]

Comment: My project uses the keyword Location in many places doing a general search doesn't help. I just walked through the whole app with permissions off to see what crashed